# Writing wrappers around stl classes with iterators in c++

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

I am trying to write wrapper classes around `std::list` and `std::vector` with their own iterators so that I can then write a superclass for both of those classes and their iterators.  My current code looks basically like this:

```
template <class T>
class MyCollection
{
//Not sure how to write this class.
public:
    class iterator
    {
        //Not sure how to write this class either
        //I think MyVector::iterator and MyList::iterator
        //should inherit from this class
    };
};

template<class T>
class MyVector : public MyCollection<T>
{
private:
    vector<T> data;
public:
    MyVector(int * start, int * end) : data(start, end) {}
    class iterator : vector<T>::iterator
    {
        iterator(typename vector<T>::iterator i) : vector<T>::iterator(i) {}
    };
    iterator begin() { return iterator(data.begin()); }
};

template<class T>
class MyList : public MyCollection<T>
{
private:
    list<T> data;
public:
    Mylist(int * start, int * end) : data(start, end) {}
    class iterator : list<T>::iterator
    {
        iterator(typename list<T>::iterator i) : list<T>::iterator(i) {}
    };
    iterator begin() { return iterator(data.begin()); }
};
```

I would like to be able to have some code that does this:

```
int ints[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
MyList<int> l(ints, ints+5);
MyCollection<int> * c = &l;
MyCollection<int>::iterator i = c->begin();
```

and after that code executes, I would like to be able to iterate through the `MyList l` using `i`.

I feel like there needs to be a `virtual begin()` member function in `MyCollection`, but I cannot figure out what the proper return type should be.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  It's entirely possible that the current organization of my code is totally wrong. That's just what I've tried.  My goal is just to get it so that the example driver code above can work, so an answer may involve a total restructuring of the code. I'm really just looking for suggestions. I don't need a complete answer.

Comment: Why do you need a superclass for the standard templates? Never seen that before.

Comment: @BoPersson, it's for a homework assignment. I am not looking for an answer to the problem. Just some guidance.

Comment: One problem is that `std::list::iterator` is a `BidirectionalIterator`, while `std::vector::iterator` is a `RandomAccessIterator`. The best you can do is make `MyCollection::iterator` have the functionality a `BidirectionalIterator` does (seeing as `RandomAccessIterator` requires `BidirectionalIterator`). You can't make it have the functionality that a `RandomAccessIterator` does, because that wouldn't work at all with `std::list::iterator`.

Comment: @Cornstalks, that's fine. I'm really just trying to get the functionality of iterating through the collection.

Comment: "I feel like there needs to be a virtual begin() member function in MyCollection, but I cannot figure out what the proper return type should be." `MyCollection<T>::iterator`?

Comment: @Jueecy, yeah I tried that, but then the sublasses' `begin()` funtions cannot return `MyVector<T>::iterator` and `MyList<T>::iterator` respectively. They would have to return a `MyCollection<T>::iterator`, which, unless I figure out a different way to restructure this code, does not inherit any of the functionality from the stl iterators.

Comment: @Daniel, I'm pretty sure you can change the return type there.

Comment: @Jueecy, no you cannot change the return type of a virtual member function.

Comment: @Jueecy, you can only do covariant return in C++ when the return type is a pointer or a reference, which is not what I want.

Comment: 1) This reduces the idea of generic programming (C++ templates) to Java-like generics. One concept of generic programming is to avoid these class hierarchies and virtual functions. Generic programming _requires_ different iterator types. 2) If you really want to do this, the `iterator` needs different implementations for list (using the links of the linked list) and vector (can increment a pointer). Therefore, you either have to use polymorphic iterators (ptrs to iterators) or some polymorphism _inside_ the iterator object.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't write a wrapper for `std::vector` and `std::list` in this case for the sole purpose of using std::list or std::vector uniformly. You don't need to.
What you want is to use type erasure in a similar way to what you can find [here](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html).

The whole idea for you would be to implement only `MyCollection<T>` with a type erased iterator and use type erased iterator for traversing any of the collections. No need for `MyList<T>` or `MyVector<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

`MyCollection::begin` should return a `MyCollection::iterator`, by convention. Therefore `MyVector::begin()` should return something that's *at least* a `MyCollection::iterator`, too. It may be a more derived type, though.

In your case, `MyVector::begin()` returns a `MyVector::iterator`, which is not derived from `MyCollection::iterator`. That's why it fails.